# Hosting Vue on a subdomain Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: apache, vue.js

I have 2 vue apps that are essentially copies of each other with a few differences however they are deployed to the same server (ubuntu/apache)

The first app is on the root domain e.g. `https://example.com`

The second is on a subdomain e.g. `https://second.example.com`

Both are using history mode on the router and I have followed the instructions here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html to avoid 404 errors

The app on the root domain runs fine but the subdomain app doesn't load and in the console I see "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" from app.js

From what I have read it may be that the app is looking for JS files but getting 404 responses that its trying to parse as JS but I have no idea how to fix it.

I cannot confirm that the subdomain is an issue but its the only difference in the hosting between the 2.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

You can use `window.location` to redirect your app on your subdomain. And then setup your vue-router to handle new routes.

You can find this issue in [this comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/233#issuecomment-156593789) of Evan You.

Comment: That wasn't the real url, just an example.